# Twitter share button without the twitter icon, just the sharing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I want to embed the twitter share option and the code I get is the javascript as well as this link to share:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Check out this link please" data-via="ObiWanKobi" data-related="User">Tweet</a>
```

I want the data text and all that to show BUT I want to use my own custom icon and not the twitter icon. So I took away the `class="twitter-share-button"` because that is what displays this button but once I do that then the `data-text` is lost and it just shares the link. How does one hack this to show a custom icon?

Your help = greatly appreciated

Comment: I got it to work using `<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com/WiggidyWhoa&text=Follow%20the%20%Wiggidy%20Whoa%20 target="_blank">` So yes, build your own URL. This had to be researched though. Know the parameters or look em up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is by not using their JavaScript at all, and simply building the share URL yourself:

```
http://twitter.com/share?text={…}&url={…}
```

Don’t forget to URL-encode parameter values you put in there properly.

You might want to add a `target="_blank"` to the link to open this in a new window/tab, or even add `window.open` to optionally open it in a popup with a predefined width and height.